# Having problems with cross-extension connection with the same ID

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to setup cross-extension connection in my Chrome extension, but seemingly it doesn't work. I've tried to keep it simple, only defining the `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` event listener in the background script, while I send the messages from the `background.js` console; `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`

I have disabled all my other extensions. Seems that others were having issues, having them enabled.

My setup in the console looks somewhat like this. (tried to add the onMessageExternal here too, in hopes it might work)

Image: https://i.gyazo.com/7a0c431ecc7a7e9731095c8e78a63da0.png

I should be expecting a console.log when I send and receive a message, but nothing happens. In the instances where I add a response function I get the error

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving
> end does not exist.

There doesn't seem to be any issues in the manifest either. I have added a (maybe redundant) externally_connectable tag, just in case.

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "ids": [ "*" ]
}
```

I'm loading the extension, unpacked, in Brave Browser and Google Chrome. Is it because I need two individual devices to make it work?
Been struggling to find documentation on this, but I hope you guys can help out!

Comment: chrome.runtime messages can't be sent by the same page to itself. It's a useless scenario so why do you do it? Cross-extension means two different extensions are communicating.

Comment: @wOxxOm I might have phrased it wrong or misinterpreted it. I mean that two users that have my extension installed, can send messages to each other. Something like Peer-to-peer.

Comment: No, chrome.runtime messaging can't be used between browsers/devices.

Comment: Is there an alternative for the same peer-to-peer-style messaging, then? I should also specify that I don't mean to direct messages to specific users, but just to everyone who has the extension.

Comment: Extensions don't have a special API for this. Try finding some standard web stuff.